# Counts table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
    Type            B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
1   Simple_repeat   0   0   0   0   0
2   Simple_repeat   0   1   0   0   1
3   Simple_repeat   10  1   9   1   35
4   Simple_repeat   3   5   2   7   10
5   Simple_repeat   8   1   1   9   13
6   Satellite       0   0   0   0    0
```

And I want to make a table of uniqe `Types`.
 So, my desired **output** :

```
    Type            B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
1   Simple_repeat   21  8   12  17  59
2   Satellite        0  0    0   0   0
```

I tried using `table` without success. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     group_by(Type) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Or

```
aggregate(.~Type, df, sum)
```

Or

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), Type]
```